# Limit Taxonomy Parents

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, functions, filters

I've got a custom taxonomy set up as hierarchical, with a custom function to limit the number of categories the user can select to one. I also need to limit the depth that this custom taxonomy can have. I don't want the user to be able to set up sub-taxonomies. Is there a way to remove the "parent" functionality from my custom taxonomy?

Alternatively, if there's a way to limit the number of tags a user can select, that'd work equally well.

---

I'm having a hard time explaining this, so here's a bulleted list:

- The user should only be able to select one of each taxonomy term for each post
- Taxonomy terms should not be able to have parents
- The user should be encouraged to select from predefined terms, rather than creating new terms, although it should still be possible to create new terms.

Essentially what I'm looking for is a combination of features from both hierarchical and non-hierarchical, along with limiting how many can be selected. It's complicated, I know.

In my experience, hierarchical taxonomies encourage users to stick to the pre-built structure more than non-hierarchical taxonomies do. This is because the primary interface for selecting hierarchical terms is a group of check boxes, with the secondary interface being an area to add new terms.

Non-hierarchical taxonomies encourage the user to be more free form, because the primary interaction method is a box where you type in terms, with the secondary being the ability to select predefined terms.

Because of this, I think the ideal way to go is a hierarchical taxonomy with it's sibling features disabled.

So the point of all this is to ensure a couple of odd features on this site will always work. These are:

- Pseudo breadcrumbs that are based off of completely separate taxonomies
- Combined taxonomy archive pages for two completely separate taxonomies

I've built these two features fairly dynamically, and as long as my client doesn't change how their content is structured, this should all work. I'm just worried if they start giving hierarchical taxonomies parents that stuff isn't going to work as expected, so I'd like to just disable that functionality.

Comment: So you want a non-hierarchical hierarchical taxonomy? Can I ask why you're doing all of this? Some background context would be helpful

Comment: Added more detail to the original post.